# Java xor Decoder

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, decode, xor

We have found files encoded using XOR Encryption, but Im newbie on JAVA, please how to decrypt XOR using this xor encoder.

Comment: "how to decode XOR using this xor encoder?" finding the corresponding XOR decoder...

Comment: Please do not disrespect us by copying and pasting the same text in order to bypass the minimum length restriction. That restriction is in place in order to get you to adequately explain the problem or question. Copy/pasting the same useless information is extremely rude and disrespectful to the users you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**. If you can't follow the guidelines here, feel free to go elsewhere for help.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to bypass the minimum but it was copied twice.

Comment: Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is generating a random int (4 bytes) and using it to XOR the input - it is not asking for the encryption key, it is generating it randomly. Unless the receiver has some way of knowing what the next random int is, it will not be able to decode. EG, perhaps the sender and receiver are expected to initialize their random generators with the same seed value when they start up. Regardless, it is not a real encryption algorithm, just another example of some half-cocked idea someone invented in their head. You really need to replace this code with a correct usage of encryption.